# Bell character in console hangs Windows 7

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-7, console, console-application

Printing bell character in console application causes PC with Windows 7 to hang:

- CPU is 100% loaded, process explorer is empty (no processes, no tasks that I could kill).
- Mouse cursor is moving but the system doesn't respond to clicks.
- Keyboard is still partially responding, so I can log off using start menu.
- Disabling beep service or replacing beep.sys with the same file from XP doesn't help.

**My System:** Toshiba L300, Intel GMA x3100, Realtek HD Audio, Win7 Pro, latest drivers.
**Steps to Reproduce:** "echo ", Alt+7, Enter in command prompt.
**Workaround**: Win+R, "taskkill /IM conhost.exe /F", Enter (kills all console windows).

It makes debugging and using 3-rd party console apps very annoying. How to fix the system?

Comment: @Maximus Tried `sfc /scannow`, didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Alt+7 is a dot character for me, and it does not hang my Windows 7.

Comment: @Neolist, Does hang mine. ASCII 7, Alt+07 does the same. XP not affected.

Comment: @Joric: Alt+07 works as beep for me, but doesn't hang my system (7 Pro 64 bit). Maybe problems with sound driver? (btw: sounds like a superuser question)

Comment: @DyP Tried disabling/uninstalling audio card, doesn't help.

Comment: Tried using [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) in 'hang' or 'cpu' mode to see if you can get a minidump out? If so you can then load into Windbg and type `!analyse -v` which may highlight a driver that's not behaving.

Comment: @Joric have you tried 3rd party console, like mintty, did you get the same problem when using bell-character in it?

Comment: @glcoder Just tried mintty, it solves the problem (kind of), thanks!